# ActiveAdmin and Devise CSS mixture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

i have installed ActiveAdmin and Devise, but when i trye to log in as User, it displays wrong CSS styling. have tryed many times, it still the same..

When i go to `localhost:3000/admin` -> it displays good looking Login form.

When i go to `localhost:3000/users/sign_in` -> it displays bad looking Login form, inherited from `ActiveAdmin` Login form.

I installed them like this:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hakery/ransack'
gem 'devise'

$bundle install
$rails g devise:install
$rails g active_admin:install
$rails g devise user
$rake db:migrate
```

I've tryed many different ways, looked up in internet but all information is so old.. and my stylings of devise sign in and sign up is really wrong..

This is my GemFile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
gem 'devise'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not at home and I don't have access to my PC so I am not able to give you 100% answers(name of the files etc..) however I had the same problem and I solved the same issue by putting the stylesheet of activeadmin into the vendors directory.

Comment: Wow, thank you!! saved whole day for me :) It really works! and why nobody mentioned that before :)

Comment: Glad I could save you from google arround for the whole afternoon :)